problems with not being able to open synaptic
E: Conflicting values ​​set for Signed-By option with respect to source https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ noble: /etc/apt/keyrings/boot-repair.gpg != -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

This question is similar to: "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
